# NodeJS: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I made a HTTP API using `Express` in `Node.js` for CRUD operations. This works partly, but when I make a `GET` request an error shows up: 
`TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.
Other HTTP methods (e.g. `POST` and `DELETE`) do work.

This is my model:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const coment = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    text: {type: String, required: true},
    author_coment: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

const vote = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    author_vote: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    vote: {type: Boolean, required: true},
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
})


const book = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    author: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    sinopsis: {type: String, required: true},
    text: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Text'},
    creation_date:  {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    cover: {type: String},
    coments: [coment],
    votes: [vote]
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', book);
```

This is my `GET` function:

```js
// [GET: Book info]
router.get('/info/:book_id', function (req, res) {
    Book.findById(req.params.book_id, (err, book) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        res.status(200).send(book);
    });
});
```

Here is my User model:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const user = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', user);
```

Edit:

After some digging, I found out what was the problem, I had another function that had this url: `/: skip/: talk`so it was executed that one instead of what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you cannot serialize an object which has a reference to itself.

Here is an example :

```
const foo = {};
foo.bar = foo
```

Here, I created an object called `foo`. I added a property called `bar` referencing `foo`.

Then the object `foo` cannot be serialized anymore because it has an infinite "property tree". If you use the example I wrote before, this is perfectly valid :

```
foo.bar.bar.bar.bar.bar.bar.bar
```

The only solution is to extract the values you need manually. You can ease the process by using destructuring.

Comment: Thx for answering, I understand this, but I can't see where in my code I'm referencing an object to itself

Comment: @DmytoHolota Can you tell me where does the error come from ? Which file & line, so I can check the source code if it is from one of the modules you are using

Comment: After some digging, I found out what was the problem, I had another function that had this url: `/: skip/: talk so it was executing that one instead of what I wanted. *FACEPALM*. @Seblor thx, for helping!

Comment: Ah okay. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

When I had to convert a circular structure to JSON I used the following route:

```
route.post('/pay',async(req,res)=>{

  try {
    const link = 'https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/v1/transactions'

    const obj = {"transaction_details": {"order_id":"order-12","gross_amount": 5000}}

    const data = await axios.post(link,obj,
      { 
        headers : {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Basic ${Base64.encode('*******')}`  
        }
      })


      const koin = data.data.token
      transaction.create({
        order_id : obj.transaction_details.order_id,
        gross_amount : obj.transaction_details.gross_amount,
        token : koin
      })
      console.log(data.data.token)

      res.json(data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

})
```

Comment: @seblor can help

Comment: For some reasons, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I was using `async await` and I left out `await` when doing a mongoose promise like `var result = await Product.find()`. When I left out `await` it returned a promise.

So when I did `res.send({result})` that is what caused the circular error.