# How to solve: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON. Using Node and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to get a single item from CosmosDB through its Id. I am using `res.send(docResponse)` to send the response to the Postman but this is giving me an error, I am using Postman to test the Api's.

```
app.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        var id = req.params.id;

        const dbResponse = await cosmosClient.databases.createIfNotExists({
            id: databaseId
        });
        let database = dbResponse.database;
            
        const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({id: containerId});

        const docResponse = await container.item(id, 1).read();

        // res.send(docResponse)
        res.json(docResponse);

        
    } catch (error) {
        
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send("Error with database query: " + error.body);
        
    }

})
```

I have also used `res.json(docResponse)` but the error is the same.

I am getting this as an error

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'CosmosClient'
    |     property 'databases' -> object with constructor 'Databases'
    --- property 'client' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (C:\Users\abbas.haider\Desktop\node azure\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\abbas.haider\Desktop\node azure\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at C:\Users\abbas.haider\Desktop\node azure\app.js:92:13
```

Comment: There are [quite a number of questions about that error on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+Converting+circular+structure+to+JSON) Perhaps you could look through those and see if any answer your question?

Comment: what does console.log(docResponse) give u?

Comment: try   res.resource;

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial console.log(docResponse) gives the correct output. Error is only when I try to res.send it.

Comment: Can you try sending docResponse.item in the response? As per documentation, read returns a promise for ItemResponse. read<T>(options?: RequestOptions): Promise<ItemResponse<T>>.. here the itemresponse object has a property "item".

Comment: Is there any progress sir? Feel free to add the details on further issue if you met. Thanks in advance : )

Answer (score 0):

Try `res.send(docResponse.resource);` instead? Here's my testing result.

[image]

Here's a [vivid explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50470891/14574199) on this error, and according to the error message, it's obvious to know `docResponse` isn't a suitable response object, and you need to extract the response object manually.